# How to get particular row of input value if i click any row of the table in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to get the input value from the `nth` row of a table but I am unable to get under the td value

I tried this

```
var Clo_Bal = $(thisid).parent().parent().children('.7').html();
```

but I'm unable to get the value.

Here's how my table is generated:

```js
var results = '<div  style="overflow:auto;"><table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered table-hover dataTable no-footer">';
results += '<thead><tr><th scope="col"></th><th scope="col" >Sno</th><th scope="col" >Agentid</th><th scope="col">Date</th><th scope="col">AgentName</th><th scope="col">Op_Balance</th><th scope="col">SaleValue</th><th scope="col">PaidAmount</th><th scope="col">ClosingValue</th><th scope="col"></th></tr></thead></tbody>';
var k = 1;
for (var i = 0; i < msg.length; i++) {
  results += '<tr><td><input id="btn_poplate" type="button" onclick="getme(this)" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update" /></td>';
  //k++;
  results += '<td scope="row"  style="text-align:center;">' + k + '</td>';
  results += '<th scope="row" class="1" style="text-align:center;">' + msg[i].AgentId + '</th>';
  results += '<td class="2">' + msg[i].inddate + '</td>';
  results += '<td class="3">' + msg[i].AgentName + '</td>';
  results += '<td class="4">' + msg[i].opp_balance + '</td>';
  //results += '<td><input id="txt_OpBal" data-title="Code" style="width:65px;" onkeyup="CLChange(this);" class="4"  value="' + msg[i].opp_balance + '"/></td>';
  results += '<td><input  id="txt_SaleValue" class="5" style="width:65px;" value="' + msg[i].salesvalue + '"/></td>';
  results += '<td><input id="txt_PaidAmount" class="6" style="width:65px;" value="' + msg[i].paidamount + '"/></td>';
  results += '<td><input  id="txt_CloBal" class="7" style="width:65px;" value="' + msg[i].clo_balance + '"/></td>';
  results += '<td><input  id="txt_Sno" class="8" style="width:65px;display:none;"  value="' + msg[i].sno + '"/></td></tr >';
  k++;
}
results += '</table></div>';
$("#div_BrandData").html(results);
```

[image]

Comment: What happens instead? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: (offtopic) Please learn about [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: `.html();` gets the html.  `input`s do not have html, they have values:  use `.val()`

Comment: `.children()` only finds elements that are direct-descendants, it will never find the `input` because `.parent().parent()` clearly goes above `.7`'s `td`.   It's unclear what `thisid` is, it looks like the `btn_poplate`[sic] but **id's must be unique**  (which it isn't as you generate multiple) so assuming `this` is in a click() handler, then you need:  `$(this).closest("tr").find('.7').val();`

Comment: i tried  .val()  and check screen short

Comment: please help me ,how can i get value .please check my screen short then you can easily under stand

Comment: See my other comment - children() won't find the input

Comment: Again: 1) you're using an id `$("#btn_poplate")` will only find the **first** btn_populate, so your code will only return values for the first row.  Change to `this` for an event handler (you've not shown this code)

Comment: Again: 2) .parent().parent() is the **row**, row.children() will only find `td` elements - you're looking for an `input` inside a `td` so use `.find(".5").val()`

Answer (score 0):

If you select nthRow

`tr:eq(${nthRow - 1})` selects the nth row within the table body, with nthRow being the row number minus 1 to account for zero-based indexing.

`td:eq(7)` selects the 8th td element (index 7) within the selected row. This assumes you want to select the td element in the 8th column of that row.

```
var nthRow = 3;
var Clo_Bal = $(`#myTable tbody tr:eq(${nthRow - 1}) td.7`).text();
console.log(Clo_Bal);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: This answer looks like it answers the *original* question about getting values from an `nth row` - the question has been updated to remove this part.